# SPSS - pass values of three dates fields into file name

Tags: spss

My dataset has three date fields (adate10): Period, Version, and Created. The values for each field are identical for all cases. Let's say the values are:

```
Period = 10/01/17
Version = 11/15/17
Created = 11/25/17
```

I would like to pass all three dates into a `SAVE OUTFILE='C:\Users\Inventory ? ? ?...` command so the file name is:

```
C:\MyData\Inventory p20171001 v20171115 c20171125.sav
```

How I can pass the values of these three date fields into the save command? I assume Python is the way to go, but cannot figure out the syntax. I see several solutions at the link below, but they all involve only one date field; I have three. (And even when I tried with one date I couldn't get any of them to work).

http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/include-value-from-variable-in-filename-when-saving-td4326879.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a little Python:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM.
import spss, spssdata

# names of date variables (case sensitive)
varlist = ['period', 'version', 'created'] 

# fetch dates from dataset and format them to YYYYMMDD
data = spssdata.Spssdata(indexes=(varlist), cvtDates=(varlist))
dates = [date.strftime("%Y%m%d") for date in data.fetchone()]
data.close()

# Create 'save command' command and submit it to spss
spss.Submit(r"""
SAVE OUTFILE = 'C:\MyData\Inventory p{0} v{1} c{2}.sav'.
""".format(*dates))
END PROGRAM.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the results you need with syntax only:

```
TEMPORARY.
select if $casenum=1.
format Period Version Created (f11).
write out="C:\MyData\save with dates in name.sps"   
    /"save out='C:\MyData\Inventory p", Period, " v",  Version, " c", Created, ".sav' ".
exe.
insert file="C:\MyData\save with dates in name.sps".
```

Comment: BTW this is similar to one of the solutions in the link you posted - but it can work easily with any number of dates (or other values from the data itself)